# Removing all space from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that I need to remove spaces from, for example it returns like

`[book, row boat,rain coat]`

However, I would like to remove all the white spaces.

All the guides I saw online said to use `.replace`, but it seems like that only works for strings. Here is my code so far.

```
function trimArray(wordlist)
{
    for(var i=0;i<wordlist.length;i++)
    {
        wordlist[i] = wordlist.replace(/\s+/, "");
    }

}
```

I have also tired `replace(/\s/g, '');`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to replace individual element: `wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].replace(/\s+/, "");`. Try using something like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it's a much cleaner approach. Note that your replacement function will replace any whitespace. If you want to just trim, use the `trim` function: `wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].trim()`

Comment: `[book, row boat,rain coat]` - Doesn't look like a string array. Is this one string or are you getting back `[" book", "  row", "  boat", " coat"]`

Comment: Do you want ALL whitespace or just the preceding and trailing whitespace? So if your array is something like this: `["cat food","dogs ","fish tank"]` do you want the spaces within `cat food` and `fish tank` gone too? Or will there never be any spaces within the strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost you need to enclose the words in your array quotes, which will make them into strings. Otherwise in your loop you'll get the error that they're undefined variables. Alternatively this could be achieved in a more terse manner using `map()` as seen below:

```js
const arr = ['book', 'row boat', 'rain coat'].map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, ''));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all of the spaces, even those within the text:

```js
    const result = ['  book','  row boat  ','rain coat  '].map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    console.log(result);
```

and this will only remove preceding and trailing spaces:

```js
    const result = ['  book',' row boat ','rain coat   '].map(str => str.trim());
    console.log(result);
```